# bootstrap stacking containers for slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question for stacking containers on bootstrap.

I wish to make a page that is similar to a powerpoint presentation where in an image is shown and upon click, it hides the current container and moves on to the next. This design would require the containers/slides to stack on top of each other in order.  I wish to have 10 containers/slides prepared on page load.

So far, the closest thing that I can think of using is the "tab" feature of bootstrap.

Is there any other better solution to it?

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active">
           ......
        </div>
</div>
```

But the problem with my solution is that the tab buttons are shown. What I just need is to have the stacked containers to show up one after the other after clicking on them.

Comment: [Is this what you're describing?](http://jsfiddle.net/GBJR6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use carousel of bootstrap instead of tab

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel